# Для чего нужно использовать SoftDeletes в своих проектах?

Tags: laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста для чего нужно использовать SoftDeletes в своих проектах ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запись use SoftDeletes; в модели говорит о том что её элементы можно мягко удалять:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

А само удаление можно сделать через контроллер

```
User::where('email', 'youremail@example.com')->softDeletes();
```

Когда вы «мягко» удаляете модель, она на самом деле остаётся в базе данных, но в БД устанавливается её атрибут deleted_at.

Comment: А подскажите для чего и где можно применить данный способ ?

Comment: Всё просто: приложение - доска объявлений, пользователи могут мягко удалять свои объявления для того чтобы потом их восстановить. Примите пожалуйста ответ, если это так!)